# What does "respect the API" mean?

Tags: api

On some websites that provide API service, they always mention that "Respect their API". I think when a website provide their API, they allow users to use them in a convenient way. We cannot really change the code or the output that we retrieve from the API.

I'm just wondering what do we need to do to actually "respect their API" and what kinds of action are counted toward "disrespect their API"?

Comment: It probably means don't send ten million requests at once.

Answer (score 1):

An action that compromises the API's security, speed, or use can be construed as "disrespecting the API." From [CAPEC.org](https://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/113.html):

> An attacker manipulates the processing of Application Programming Interface (API) resulting in the API's function having an adverse impact upon the security of the system or application implementing the API. This can allow the attacker to execute functionality not intended by the API implementation, possibly compromising the system or application which integrates the API. API Abuse can take on a number of forms. For example, the API may trust that the calling function properly validates its data and thus it may be manipulated by supplying metacharacters or alternate encodings as input, resulting in any number of injection flaws, including SQL injection, cross-site scripting, or command execution. Another example could be API methods that should be disabled in a production application but were not, thus exposing dangerous functionality within a production environment.

Comment: thanks, i saw that answer before and it's right but it's just the misuse/abuse API, not really cover all the actions that disrespect the API. I would like to learn more about what other kinds of action that disrespect the API service.